# After El Capitan update, I cannot sign in to anything with my Apple ID: '"This action could not be completed. Try again"

Tags: macos, imac, apple-id

I updated OSX last night to El Capitan and after the update, and restarting my iMac(2014) a few times, I cannot sign in with my Apple ID.

The initial restart gave me the error: "This action could not be completed. Try again." I assumed I had forgotten my password, so I went through the procedure of resetting my password. I was then allowed access.

When I then tried logging in to another service requiring an Apple ID (Mac App Store in particular), I get the error "This action could not be completed..."

Restarting my machine does nothing. Should I revert to an older version of OSX?

[image]

Comment: The error message indicates that it cannot connect to the store for some reason, not that your username/password is invalid.  Have you confirmed that your have Internet?

Comment: Hi Allan, my internet connection is fine, I've managed to connect via the web, its just when I try to use services like the mac app store or iCloud. This only started happening after I upgraded to El Capitan, so I'm assuming there's something up there. Maybe something on Keychain isn't working as it should?

Comment: Can you post a screen shot of the error in your original question?  Shift-Command-4 is the key combo to do a area screen grab.

Comment: Screenshot added, I'm hoping to avoid something like what was posted in [this question](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/235136/os-x-server-cant-upgrade-or-configure-app-store-fails-this-action-could-not/235140#235140), I'm also reluctant to start messing with file system permissions like in [this question](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/7306830?start=0&tstart=0)

Comment: *SOLVED(potentially)... I took a wild stab in the dark that iTunes was the problem, and so updated iTunes first, then attempted a sign in... once the iTunes sign in was successful it seems that everything else is now able to sign in... at least the Mac app store.

Comment: If the iTunes fix worked, then all is good.  Just add your solution as an answer. a As for the the permissions, you don't have to worry about it - sometimes permissions get corrupt and they need to be fixed.

Answer (score 11):

Execute the following commands in Terminal:

```
sudo mkdir -p /Users/Shared
sudo chown root:wheel /Users/Shared
sudo chmod -R 1777 /Users/Shared
```

Comment: That saves me a day!!!!

Comment: No words...I have no idea how this is related, but saves my XCode sign-in problem.

Comment: Spent an hour with Apple support - could not fix it. But this little advice solved the problem. Thank you!

Comment: I guess it wan't a good idea to remove Shared folder from Users in the first place :-)

Comment: I've put up with an annoying "sign into iCloud" popup on my Mac for months, with the password not working and nobody at Apple able to help. Couldn't update Xcode either via the App Store. This solution just fixed both of those problems. Thank you!

Comment: Note that this also solved the problem for me on High Sierra, but I had to log out and back in first.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up updating iTunes then signing in, after the update completed and a restart.
Once the iTunes sign in was successful everything else was able to sign in.
Hope that helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

I don't recall where I found these, but the following commands in Terminal worked for me:

```
sudo mkdir -p /Users/Shared
sudo chown root:wheel /Users/Shared
sudo chmod -R 1777 /Users/Shared
```

Comment: This is the same answer as [this one](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/253741/121968) - it doesn't add any value and should be deleted.